# How to make a slow browser go fast?

Tags: safari, internet, web-browsing, web-browser

I've had my MacBook Air for about six months. Now all the browsers are extremely sluggish — sometimes taking minutes to load a web page that would have used to take under one second to load back when everything was new.

## Questions

1. What's causing the sluggish browser response? (Most likely.)
2. What is a stepwise procedure to troubleshoot and/or fix it?

#### Configuration Details

- O/S: OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
- Memory: 4 GB @ 1600MHz DDR
- Browsers: Safari, Chrome

Comment: Usually memory, but some versions of Safari were slow for me; fixed in 9.0.1 [could also be DNS latency]. What OS & RAM, what browser/version? How many tabs open at once?

Answer (score 1):

Changing my DNS settings to Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 seems to help a little but might not be the comprehensive solution I was looking for.

#### Procedure

Bottom toolbar > System Preferences > Network > Advanced... > DNS > + > 8.8.8.8 > + > 8.8.4.4

Or, via command line:

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

[The procedure is detailed here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/02/change-dns-command-line-mac-os-x/).